# Como definir posição da Section

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-3

pessoal tenho uma pagina web em bootstrap com 4 sections que se você usar os botões na nav bar altera entre as sections, porem quando eu clico no botão não fica centralizado ele come um pouco da próxima section teria algum truque em css ou js pra manter centralizada quando clicar no botão

Answer (score 0):

O ideal é mostrar o codigo para que possamos definir, mas crie uma classe para esta section e defina:

```
position: relative;
left: -10 !important; //ou seja, a distancia necessária para não "comer" a outra section
```

Utiliza o !important pra sobrepor qualquer outro estilo ja existente na section